# Envelope detector for AM signals

Tags: signal, signal-processing, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

How or what are the constraints for deciding factors of envelope detector for AM?

As far as I know that charging time of  the capacitor should be below 20T where T is periodic time of carrier and discharging should not give negative clipping, but I cannot see how to apply them.

[image: Question 1]

Question 2

[image: Question 2]

Comment: Surely "below 20T where T is frequency of carrier" should read "where \$ T = \frac {1}{f} \$ where *f* is the frequency of the carrier? T would be then be the periodic time of the carrier which would make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

You've given no specification for modulation bandwidth versus carrier. The finest way to extract AM modulation is the synchronous detector using a mixer to combine the AM-signal and a fixed-amplitude fixed-phase same-frequency local oscillator that is phaselocked.